# Android AudioRecord vs. MediaRecorder for recording audio

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiorecord

I want to record human voice on my Android phone. I noticed that Android has two classes to do this: [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) and [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html). Can someone tell me what's the difference between the two and what are appropriate use cases for each?

I want to be able to analyse human speech in real-time to measure amplitude, etc. Am I correct in understanding that AudioRecord is better suited for this task?

I noticed on the official Android [guide webpage for recording audio](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html), they use MediaRecorder with no mention of AudioRecord.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you want to do your analysis while recording is still in progress, you need to use `AudioRecord`, as `MediaRecorder` automatically records into a file. `AudioRecord` has the disadvantage, that after calling `startRecording()` you need to poll the data yourself from the `AudioRecord` instance. Also, you must read and process the data fast enough such that the internal buffer is not overrun (look in the logcat output, `AudioRecord` will tell you when that happens).

Comment: Do you have sample code of AudioRecord? Most of the ones I've found are MediaRecorder...

Comment: @RommelParas look in this class in "telegram" for android source. https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/MediaController.java

Comment: @David Do you know of a more basic sample? One that works on its own?

Comment: @androiddeveloper unfortunately no.

Answer (score 42):

As I understand `MediaRecorder` is a black box which gives compressed audio file on the output and `AudioRecorder` gives you just raw sound stream and you have to compress it by yourself.

`MediaRecorder` gives you the max amptitude from last call of `getMaxAmplitude()` method so you can implement a sound visualizer for example.

So in most cases `MediaRecorder` is the best choice except those  in which you should make some complicated sound processing and you need access to the raw audio stream.

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning the getMaxAmplitude() method. That is most likely all I need.

Comment: How can I implement visualizer using MediaRecorder?

Comment: What does getMaxAmplitude help exactly here? Don't you need to get the current one at every single moment for the visualizer?

Answer (score 21):

AudioRecorderer first saves data in minBuffer then it is copied from there to the temporary buffer, in MediaRecorder it is copied to files.
In AudioRecorder we need the api setRecordPosition() to copy the saved data at required position, whereas in MediaRecorder the file pointer is does this job to set the position of the marker.
AudioRecorder can be used to those apps which run on an emulator this can be done by providing low sample rate such as 8000, while using MediaRecorder the audio cannot be recorded using emulator.
In AudioRecord the screen sleep after sometime, while in MediaRecorder the screen does not sleep.