# Live video recording in Android

Tags: android, video, recording

We have a requirement for an android application that can record live video from a camera  and save it to a file. The application will detect portrait/landscape mode of the cell phone and will draw a rectangle as an overlay over the live video of the camera. This rectangle will always be drawn in landscape mode and will have an aspect ratio of 16:9 . Only the contents inside the rectangle need to be recorded.Is it possible to record only the contents inside the rectangle

Regards
Sabarish

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is record the video as the camera on the device will give it to you and you process it afterwards: either using a library on the device (might cost you a lot of battery) or off-device, on a server the app connects to. On the server you crop the video using one of the many tools out there: Virtualdub, AVI Demux, AVISynth, Xvid4PSP up to Vegas, Premiere and FCP.

"Cropping" a video means decode, and re-encode.

I have only worked with audio and maybe you find something similar to the audio APIs where you have:

- high-level API [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) which does almost all the job for you (you can only change a few recording and encoding parameters)
- low-level API [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) which allows live processing of the audio stream while recording.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886872/android-audiorecord-vs-mediarecorder-for-recording-audio) explains the difference.

Maybe you find something similar in the video world.